# Android: Bring the alarm dismiss screen to the front

Tags: android

I'm writing an app that uses an AlarmManager and I would like several options for the user to choose what happens when the alarm goes off.

I want one option to launch the standard alarm dismiss screen, the one with the big red x that you swipe left/right to dismiss. Is there an intent I can use to launch this screen, along with the alarm ringtone that goes along with it?

It would definitely save me the trouble of creating my own activity to mimic this, but I haven't been able to find the code to do this yet. 
I don't want to use the intent 
Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
to set my alarm because it launches another activity and doesn't allow customization of what to happen when the alarm goes off.

Any links or help would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid not, since the standard alarm might be resident in the package of "GoogleDeskClock.apk" and the activity might change during the release. So I won't recommend you to use the activity defined in other apk other than in yours.

If you do like the style of default alarm, you can simply copy the code from the standard deskclock, please refer to the AOSP project at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/master

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'll use snippets from that code to implement my own custom activity to launch on alarm finish. It looks like that is my only option.